# How to return unauthorized response from before hook in feathersJS

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I have parts of app (modules) that gonna be forbidden for certain people, so I wanna check that in before hook and send unauthorized response if its needed.
I'm successfully throwing error on backend, but on my frontend I still get successful response as if there was no error.

Here is how my code looks like:

1.Function that checks if app is forbidden for user that sent request:

```
        function isAppForbidden(hook) {
          let forbiddenApps = [];
          hook.app.services.settings.find({
            query: {
              $limit: 1,
              $sort: {
                createdAt: -1
              }
            }
          }).then(res => {
            let array = hook.params.user.hiddenApps;
            if(array.indexOf('qualitydocs') >= 0 || res.data[0].forbiddenApps.indexOf('qualitydocs') >= 0) {
              hook.response = Promise.reject({error: '401 Unauthorized'}); 
                 //this part is important, the rest not so much    
                //what im expecting to do here is just to return unauthorized response                                                  
            }
          });
          return hook;
        }
```

But this for now just throws error on backend like:
"error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
   { error: { code: '401', message: 'Unauthorized' } } } code=401, message=Unauthorized"

And frontend still gets successful response (200 with requested data)

And I just call this function in before hooks:

```
  before: {
    all: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
      hook => includeBefore(hook),
      hook => isAppForbidden(hook) //here, rest is not important
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [(hook) => {
      hook.data.authorId = hook.params.user.id;
    }],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
```

the response im expecting to get, looks something like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution... the key was to wrap the content of function in promise... so it now looks like this:

```
function isAppForbidden(hook) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    hook.app.services.settings.find({
      query: {
        $limit: 1,
        $sort: {
          createdAt: -1
        }
      }
    }).then(res => {
      if (hook.params.user.hiddenApps.indexOf('qualitydocs') >= 0 || res.data[0].forbiddenApps.indexOf('qualitydocs') >= 0) {
        reject(new errors.NotAuthenticated());
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    })
  })
}
```

and it works as a charm

[image]